# Quick question on triangle similarity

Tags: geometry

Are these two triangles similar? I'm not sure whether the $AA$ rule works regardless of whether the angles are in the same vertices of the triangle or not. Here I've interchanged $a$ and $b$ so the triangle cannot be rotated to get the other one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it can be flipped over...
Here's a [condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29#Similar_triangles) for two triangles to be similar :
They have two identical angles, which implies that their angles are all identical.

Clearly that's your case.

Comment: Ok thanks, just wanted verifcation :)